# Kilograms to Pounds and Ounces

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that converts kilograms to pounds and ounces. If the user enters 100 kilograms the result I'm expecting is 220 pounds and 7.4 ounces.

I get the correct pound value but my problem is getting the correct ounces value. I don't know what I'm missing. Also when I calculate the ounces value, how do i specify to the program that I only want the answer to the hundredth degree. For example I only want 7.4 ounces and not 7.4353?

```
import acm.program.*;
public class KilogramsToPoundsAndOunces extends ConsoleProgram {
public void run() {

    println("This program converts Kilograms into Pounds and Ounces.");

    int kilo = readInt("please enter a number in kilograms: ");

    double lbs = kilo * POUNDS_PER_KILOGRAM; 

    double oz = lbs * OUNCES_PER_POUND; 

    double endPounds = (int) oz / OUNCES_PER_POUND;

    double endOunces =  oz - (endPounds * OUNCES_PER_POUND); 

    println( endPounds + " lbs " + endOunces + "ozs");




}
private static final double POUNDS_PER_KILOGRAM = 2.2;
private static final int OUNCES_PER_POUND = 16;
}
```

Comment: Please take the kilo in double instead of int.

Comment: Why are you casting oz to INT before dividing it by ounces per pound?

Comment: @Jim I'm trying to use type cast for endPounds to only calculate the total number of pounds that I want.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use `System.out.printf` and format the output there:

```
System.out.printf("%d lbs %.1f ozs", endPounds, endOunces);
```

If you can't use `System.out.printf`, you can still use [`String#format`](http://goo.gl/47VSy) to format the output:

```
println(String.format("%d lbs %.1f ozs", endPounds, endOunces));
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me figure out the problem but I have not learned about strings in my class.

Comment: Don't worry, you will do it anytime. Still, there are other ways to get the result you expect i.e. using `NumberFormat` or `DecimalFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Cases where you need exact decimal value; its better to use BigDecimal data type instead of double.

The BigDecimal class provides operations for arithmetic, scale manipulation, rounding, comparison, hashing, and format conversion. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

BigDecimal provides methods to round the number to given value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DecimalFormat` to print the decimal places in desired format e.g.

```
    DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
    System.out.println( endPounds + " lbs " + dFormat.format(endOunces) + " ozs");
```

**If you want rounding done upto one decimal place**, then multiply the number by 10, round, then divide again and print as below:

```
double roundedOunces = Math.round(endOunces*10)/10.0;
DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
System.out.println( endPounds + " lbs " + dFormat.format(roundedOunces) + " ozs");
```

EDIT:

Try this for rounding:

```
  double roundedOunces = Math.round(endOunces*10)/10.0;.
```

Without rounding:

```
  double roundedOunces = endOunces*10/10.0;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely take time to look at that.

Comment: @JessicaM. Would you be able to provide some inputs to help me improving my answers? This is second answer in a row, when I think its better but looks like its not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: For the previous question, I selected his answer as best answer because his was the first solution I tried and it solved the problem. For this answer your suggestions are a little more advanced then that I'm working on right now so I really don't understand it all that much.

Comment: @JessicaM.: Its not about the first answer. Its about the best you like at the time :) Any way, just try this `double roundedOunces = Math.round(endOunces*10)/10.0;`. This means, you are wounding up to one decimal place. If you don't want to round, try this `double roundedOunces = endOunces*10/10.0;`. If you need explanation then let me know.